# Android HttpsConnection - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, https

I would like to get data from webservices of my school. I write down code in Eclipse:

```
List<Predmet> getInfo(String osobniCislo) throws IOException
    {
        String target = "https://stag-ws.zcu.cz/ws/services/rest/rozvrhy/getRozvrhByStudent?osCislo="
                + "A12B0141P"
                + "&outputFormatEncoding=windows-1250";

        URL url = new URL(target);

        HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        https.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5s timeout
        https.setRequestMethod("GET");
        https.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        https.setUseCaches(false);
        https.setDoOutput(true);
        https.connect();


        //Response cod
        int responseCode = https.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println(https.getResponseMessage());

    }
```

This code works fine in Eclipse and I get what I want. But when I copied it into Android Studio, I'm getting `500 - Server Internal Error`. I have privilige in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and others websites works fine. Do someone have idea where could be a problem?

Comment: One mistake I see right from the start is that you are attempting a GET request but calling `setDoOutput(true)` which is setting your request to POST instead. If you want to do a GET request, you don't need `setRequestMethod("GET")` or `setDoOutput(true)`. The `HttpsURLConnection` class is set to use GET requests by default.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is generated in the server, as it shows `500 - Server Internal Error`. If your code works in one IDE, it should work in another IDE if you have imported the project correctly. Check the web service you are using which is causing the error.